# 80s sci-fi short story: soldier finds tiny cylindrical alien craft; aliens use a force field to shield him from artillery

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Just wondered if anybody would be able to identify an old sci-fi short story roughly from the 80s, in which there was a soldier on a battlefield who dived into a bomb crater for protection, where he found 5 or 6 silver cylinders which turned out to be tiny alien craft.

He eventually realises they are aliens and tries to save them using notes held up to the ships. In the end it turns out he is about to be blown to bits and the alien ships use a force field to protect him from the advancing artillery.

That's roughly the way I remember it from back then. It was part of a collection of short stories I had in hard cover format, of which I can't remember the title anymore.

Comment: The size of the alien ships — and their use of force fields — makes them resemble drones (small, mobile A.I.s) from Iain M. Banks' Culture series. Their action on the battlefield sounds like a Special Circumstances recruitment operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is "[Crossfire](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71712)" (1953) by James White, first published in *New Worlds Science Fiction*, [June 1953](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_021v07_1953-06/page/n103/mode/2up), anthologized in [*Science Fiction Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?35691) (1979).

[image: 1979 cover of "Science Fiction Stories"]

The objects were found by a patrol, and they are *near* a crater (which is where the investigators shelter), but otherwise this is very close.

> Cotrell bad no difficulty in finding the upturned enemy truck with the **silver torpedoes** scattered on the ground beside it, and **the deep bomb-crater nearby** that from which the previous investigators had worked. It was an old crater, with grass growing in patches on its walls and floors. As craters go, it was fairly comfortable.
>
> [...]
>
> The enemy truck had been shot up from the air. It was lying on its side, burned out, a total wreck. The **seven silvery objects** lay close together about ten yards from the truck.

After determining that they are mostly hollow, with very thin shells and various metallic bits inside, he inspects one and can see the beings inside.

> "... Tiny, complex mechanisms linked by hair-thin wires, but so small. Our micro techniques can't touch this at all. It seems to be divided into thin-walled compartments of different sizes ... Oh, why can't I have a decent lens, everything blurs and jiggles around ... The inside is filled with a yellowish gas, and in the nose ... Wait! Something moved. It's a snail, no, two snails. But they're going too fast for snails. Maybe..."
>
> [...]
>
> "That's right," he affirmed. His voice was exultant, almost exalted. "*Spaceships.*" Seven of them. That's all they could be. It explains everything. The sudden transparency of the nose. The tiny machines, controls, wiring, little creatures working at things. They're spaceships, I tell you. An extraterrestrial life-form, and *intelligent*."

The enemy is counter-attacking over this ground, and the ships are in danger from artillery, so they show the aliens pictures to convince them to fly to safety.

> "That's *it*! Don’t you see. We draw them pictures — before and after pictures. First show ships lying peacefully, then shells falling, show ships in little pieces. Also show them taking off safely. Make the sketches simple, with clear, black lines. Stick those in front of their eyes, that should scare them away all right."

They are successful in communicating, and six of the ships fly away.  They are trying to signal the last one, when it puts up the force field.

> With desperate haste Cotrell propped his sketch up before it and dived for cover. The area was taking an awful pasting from the guns now. It was one continuous eruption. [...] They knew without a shadow of a doubt that they could have only minutes left to live, then suddenly — just like that — it stopped.
>
> It wasn't just quiet — it was utterly, deathly silent.
>
> [...]
>
> They found the force-field to be hemispherical in shape, perfectly transparent, and impenetrable to everything, including sound. It was approximately fifteen yards in diameter, and felt like warm glass. At its geometrical centre was the alien ship.

The alien ship hangs around long enough to save them from destruction, then flies off to join the rest.

Comment: DavidW, Thank you so much. I have been looking for a copy of this book for years, not knowing what it was. Now thanks to you, i have been able to get my hands on a copy. Cheers.